# How to link two pages htm with click button?

Tags: php, html, button, onclick

I have this code:

```
        <a href="init.php">

        <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="Style9" value="Se connecter" onclic= "<?php include("D:/EasyPHP-5.3.3.1/www/conn.php"); ?> " /></a>
```

I want after clicking the button to call conn.php and pass to the page init.php
here i can call conn.php but i fail to pass to init.php

Comment: the best way would be to use form action="init.php" and include conn.php within that file

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form method="POST" name="test" action="init.php">
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="Style9" value="Se connecter" />
</form>
```

Then in init.php, include the conn.php file.

```
<?php include("D:/EasyPHP-5.3.3.1/www/conn.php"); ?>
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to do, exactly?  It would probably help if you display what's going on in conn.php